# Combine multiple articles in a two-column format with title above the columns

Tags: titles, multiple-files

I am using Overleaf and trying to set an environment for a two-column text layout. I want the title as well as the names of the authors to be right above the two columns.

I got it working fine for the first title/article but whenever I add a second title/article, the title of the second one does not stand above the two columns...

So this is the **main.tex** (I'm using a custom font):

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,top=2.5cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Aileron-Regular}[    Path=./Aileron/,    Extension=.otf,]
\newfontfamily\aileronbold{Aileron-Bold}[    Path=./Aileron/,    Extension=.otf,]
\newfontfamily\aileronthin{Aileron-Thin}[    Path=./Aileron/,    Extension=.otf,]
\newfontfamily\aileronitalic{Aileron-Italic}[    Path=./Aileron/,    Extension=.otf,]
\newfontfamily\aileronthinitalic{Aileron-ThinItalic}[    Path=./Aileron/,    Extension=.otf,]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\aileronbold\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\aileronthin\leftmark \ \thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\aileronthin Example Name}

\begin{document}

\input{article1.tex}
\input{article2.tex}

\end{document}
```

This is **article1.tex**

```
\title{\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\textbf{Title of article one} \vspace{0.5em}}
\author{\textbf{Author 0} $\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ \textbf{Author 1}$\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ \textbf{Author 2} }
\date{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{quote}
\aileronthinitalic
This is a random quote in Aileron Thin.
\end{quote}

\section{Section One}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Undersection Example}

\lipsum[2-5]

\section{End}

\lipsum[6]
```

**article2.tex** looks the same as one, but it formats the titles differently:

[image: \clearpage doesn't help either]

How can i make the formatting of title2 be just the same as title1? Would I have to use "combine" in the main.tex? I'd be happy to get some advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add several `\maketitle` with the `ltxdoc` class, but taking care of reset the section counter after every title, in this way:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\title{AAAA}
\author{Foo}
\date{yesterday}
\maketitle
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{AAAA}
\section{bbbb} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{cccc} \lipsum[3-4]
\title{BBBB}
\author{Bah}
\date{tomorrow}
\maketitle
\setcounter{section}{0}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{BBBB}
\section{dddd} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{eeee} \lipsum[5-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working this way! As for the table of contents that gets created, is it possible that it shows only the multiple titles (and not the sections)? 

Also, is it possible that the table of contents is not bound to one column either but just uses the entire page layout? 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes and yes. Change `\tableofcontents` by `\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn` (the first command could be placed in the preamble)

Comment: Thanks, that also let me get the toc into one column. I also put the counter in the preamble but my toc remains empty for some reason. Is -1 set for titles in the toc?

Comment: The TOC appear only  in the **second** compilation. The `-1`  of `tocdeth` means that only the only appear the `part` level, the negative sign is because is  beyond the first level (1)  that is the section (or chapter in books-ĺike classes). The true title do not appear in the TOC in any case